# initiate a new datatable with data when a row is clicked in another datatable using Spring MVC for data generation

Tags: java, jquery, spring-mvc, datatable

Basically I want to have two tables on one page. In table 1 I want to store information related to areas, and in table 2, I want to show staff information related to the area being clicked.

My backend uses Spring MVC to generate data.

Table 1 is initiated this way:

```
function createTable1() {
            tableOne = $('#table').dataTable({
                ajax: function (data, callback, settings) {
                    var param = {};
                    param.type = "3";
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "post",
                        url: '/area/getareainfo',
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: param,
                        success: function (result) {
                           if (result) {
                                var returnData = {};
                                returnData.data = result;
                                callback(returnData);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                },

                columns: [
                    {"data": "label"},
                    {"data": "value"},
                    {"data": "count" },
                    {"data": "count" },
                    {"data": "count"}
                ]
            });
        }
```

I have a piece of very similar code for creating table 2 that I don't know if it is going to work yet (except I have `destroy`option set to `true`)

```
$('#table tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
                createTable2();
            });
```

My task is to write a controller that relay data for table 1 and table 2, connecting the data between table 1 and table 2 in some way, and have the two datatables shown and worked. How should I structure this? (I have zero experience writing Spring MVC, and ignorant how I should use ajax for getting table 2 data from table 1 information and the backend)

Thank you very much for any input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to destroy Table 2, you can use table2.ajax.reload() instead!

Also, no need to connect data between table1 and table2. You can have separate Datatables definitions for the two tables and separate AJAX urls returning JSON for the two tables. For example, assuming that your JSON for table1 looks like this:

```
{
"data": [{
        "label": "1",
        "value": "2",
        "count": "3"
    },
    {
        "label": "11",
        "value": "22",
        "count": "33"
    }
]
}
```

Then your second datatable initialization code can be as follows:

```
 tableTwo = $('#table2').dataTable({
            ajax: "/staff/getStaffInfoForArea?"+areaCode,
            columns: [
                //your columns
            ]
        });
```

where "/staff/getStaffInfoForArea?" is your server side URL appended with areaCode request parameter, and areaCode is a global javascript variable. You will have to store the row clicked on information in your areaCode variable like below:

```
 $('#table tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
            var rowSelected = tableOne.row({selected: true}).data();
            areaCode = rowSelected.label //assuming 'label' is the key which store your area specific info
            tableTwo.ajax.reload();
        });
```

On Spring MVC side, your Controller method to get you table 2 data can look like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/staff/getStaffInfoForArea", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String getPaginatedSiteIdents(@RequestParam String areaCode) {

//put all your Java code to retrieve staff info for area here
//and return a JSON string with "data" array
}
```

Of course there are a lot of specifics you need to take care of here. Hope this gives you a starting point!